# Flex container grows too much, overlapping other elements

Tags: flash, apache-flex, layout

Here's the thing. I'm using pure AS3 to do some special automatic layout of some Flex components, when I discover that some SkinnableContainers grow bigger than their content, even if they have 0 padding and the layout inside them is BasicLayout (i.e. "full-manual" layout).

Here's a screenshot and the code. This little test creates an Application and sets the layout to HorizontalLayout. Then, inside the Application container, I create two SkinnableContainers, each containing a Label with some text. I set the SkinnableContainers to have maximum 150px width, and the Labels inside them to have 100% width of their parents.

Screenshot

[image: Layout screenshot]

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:MainApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:local="*"/>
```

MainApplication.as

```
package {
  import flash.events.Event;
  import spark.components.Application;
  import spark.components.SkinnableContainer;
  import spark.components.Label;
  import spark.layouts.HorizontalLayout;
  import spark.layouts.BasicLayout;

  public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public function MainApplication() {
      super();

      var hl : HorizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
      hl.gap = 0;
      hl.paddingTop = 0;
      hl.paddingLeft = 0;
      hl.paddingRight = 0;
      hl.paddingBottom = 0;

      this.layout = hl;

      var leftBlock : SkinnableContainer = myNewContainer(0xFF0000);
      var rightBlock : SkinnableContainer = myNewContainer(0x00FF00);;
      var leftLabel : Label = myNewLabel("oranges blackberries bananas kiwis plums apples");
      var rightLabel : Label = myNewLabel("apricots peaches lemons pineapples");

      leftBlock.addElement(leftLabel);
      rightBlock.addElement(rightLabel);

      this.addElement(leftBlock);
      this.addElement(rightBlock);
    }

    private function myNewContainer(backColor : Number) : SkinnableContainer {
      var container : SkinnableContainer = new SkinnableContainer();
      container.layout = new BasicLayout();
      container.maxWidth = 150;
      container.explicitWidth = 150;
      container.opaqueBackground = backColor;
      return container;
    }

    private function myNewLabel(text : String) : Label {
      var myLabel : Label = new Label();
      myLabel.text = text;
      myLabel.percentWidth = 100;
      myLabel.setStyle("color", 0xFFFFFF);
      myLabel.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0x000000);
      return myLabel;
    }
  }
}
```

It looks to me like the SkinnableContainers (red and green backgrounds) don't care about the `maxWidth = 150;` I applied to them, but the Labels (white text on black background) respect this. I was expecting to see only the Labels, without any overextended red or green backgrounds. Is there some padding involved? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Use the `backgroundColor` style instead of the `opaqueBackground` property.

**Long answer**

If you replace that `container.opaqueBackground = backColor` with `container.setStyle("backgroundColor", backColor)` (just as you did with the Labels) the red and green zones are right where you would expect them to be.

Bear in mind that [opaqueBackground](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#opaqueBackground) is a pure AS3 property of the DisplayObject class. It has nothing to do (directly) with the Flex framework. So what you see, is those DisplayObjects somewhat overlapping, but not the Flex SkinnableContainers.

To be more precise: the SkinnableContainers extend from DisplayObject, so technically they *are* overlapping, but their graphics and contents are aligned in such a way that visually (and in any other practical way except the usage of `opaqueBackground`) they are not.

Comment: This solved it, indeed. Also, thank you for the explanation! It makes much more sense now.

Comment: Also, thanks for fixing the screenshot... I'm still learning here.